# Dronekit Android Drone Constructor doesn't accept context

Tags: android, dronekit

I try to write an Android app to read some data from my drone. In the example I saw on github and in the Javadoc the constructor of a new Drone need a context. But my Drone in Android Studio does not accept any parameter.

Build.gradle:

```
dependencies{
....
compile 'com.o3dr.android:dronekit-android:2.3.11'    
}
```

My Activity: (This is correct according to Android Studio)

```
import com.o3dr.android.client.Drone;
import android.content.Context;
...
private Drone drone;
....
final Context context = getApplicationContext();
this.drone = new Drone();
```

On the next line I get an error:

```
this.drone = new Drone(context);
```

error: Drone() in Drone cannot be applied to (android.context.Context)

Who knows where I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

```
compile 'com.o3dr.android:dronekit-android:2.3.11'
```

is an old version. Use 3.0.1 and it works.